# Creating inline SVG with JS in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm working with a local HTML5 file -- it's got `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top.  I put something like this in it:

```
<svg height="2em" width="3em" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

(no namespaces, thanks HTML5!), and it displays great in Chrome and FF4 beta.

Now I want to create the same thing but via JS.  I'm using Prototype, so I wrote something like:

```
var box = new Element('svg', {'width':'3em', 'height':'2em', 'preserveAspectRatio': 'none', 'viewBox': '0 0 100 100'});
box.appendChild(new Element('rect', {fill:'red', x:'0', y:'0', width:'100', height:'100' }));
container.appendChild(box);
```

I can see in Firebug / DOM inspector (both FF and Chrome) that it's creating the same DOM structure for this.

The only difference I see is that the attributes ("preserveAspectRatio" and "viewBox") are all-lowercase, but I tried changing the attributes in my first test (static HTML) to all-lower-case and it still works fine, so I don't think that's the problem.

Is the HTML5 SVG capability limited to static HTML, and I need to do namespaces still for adding SVG content via JS, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: (Comment because this isn't helpful) If you're doing JavaScript vector manipulation, unless you specifically need SVG output, it may be easier to just use `<canvas>`.

Comment: The way the HTML5 spec combines SGML and XML (with respect to SVG) confuses the heck out of me too :( I think you should probably consult the spec directly to see if it has any comments regarding how this case *should* be handled. If it seems like it's being handled incorrectly, file a browser bug report. Also, if you're able to provide a link to the source file, I'd be curious to take a look.

Comment: Also, I doubt it's an issue involving namespaces, as "svg" and "rect" both live in the SVG namespace, and your question implies that they are both getting rendered, albeit incorrectly. @preserveAspectRatio, on the other hand, lives in the default namespace, and so you shouldn't prefix that with a namespace even if you wanted to. I think this is more likely to be an issue of case-sensitivity for tags and attributes. As a first step, I would try it without Prototype, just using node.setAttribute/setAttributeNS, and see if it works. It could be a Prototype problem.

Comment: echo-flow: OK, standalone example coming soon...  :-)

Comment: echo-flow: Turns out it *was* a namespace issue: the elements need to be created with `createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", ...)`, which Prototype happens to have no built in (`new Element(...)`) support for.  So I guess the HTML5 SVG situation is basically "SVG without a namespace gets the namespace added during parsing (but after that it's just like XHTML before)".

Comment: P.S., the "Answer Your Question" button here isn't working for me today, so if anybody adds this as as answer, I'll mark it correct.  :-)

Comment: add the answer yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Turns out it was a namespace issue: the elements need to be created with createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", ...), which Prototype happens to have no built in (new Element(...)) support for. So I guess the HTML5 SVG situation is basically "SVG without a namespace gets the namespace added during parsing (but after that it's just like XHTML before)".
>
> P.S., the "Answer Your Question" button here isn't working for me today, so if anybody adds this as as answer, I'll mark it correct. :-)