# <script> tag in HTML lowercase or uppercase

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem using the webstorm8.0.1 IDE, I have an HTML file and I want to put a `script` tag like this

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></SCRIPT>
```

and it says "Unresolved variable or type "myfile" at line 10"

But when I put it like this in lowercase it works!!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

I am having a hard time figuring out why it works in lowercase letters and it doesn't work in uppercase letters

**this is "myfile" script:**

```
function muestraInformacion(elEvento) {
    var evento = elEvento || window.event;
    var coordenadaX = evento.clientX;
    var coordenadaY = evento.clientY;
    alert("Has pulsado el ratón en la posición: " + coordenadaX + ", " + coordenadaY);
}
document.onclick = muestraInformacion;
```

---

I didn't put again the `script` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

In my file is that optional or is this that is causing the problem?

thanks in advance sorry for the bad english

Comment: You should always lowercase your tags.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the webstorm software and not a programming issue. As for uppercase vs lowercase tags, it doesn't matter. They are not case sensitive.

Comment: HTML is case-insensitive, so whether you write `<script>`, `<SCRIPT>` or `<ScRiPt>` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Just ignore the error. It should run fine in the browser.

The html tag and attribute names are case - insensitive. But the attribute values are not.

The IDE might be misnterpreting things.

It **will** work in the browser.

However I **strongly** advise you to use lowercase. It is much compressible than caps.

Answer (score 0):

its always better to use lowercase, its not really matter in html ,W3C recommends lowercase in HTML , and demands lowercase tags in XHTML.
so its god practice to use lowercase always.

you can see:
http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_web_standards_model_-_HTML_CSS_and_JavaScript

Comment: Please help here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319537/html-5-inline-svg-and-namespace-awareness-for-svg-dom