# XPath for SVG element with fill variable?

Tags: html, xml, svg, xpath, css-variables

I tried to use XPath to select an `svg` element's `fill` attribute value, which uses an CSS variable, but I'm getting nothing back.

HTML:

```
<svg class="unf-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" 
     fill="var(--N400, #6C727C)" style="display: inline-block; 
     vertical-align: middle;">
  <path d="M9.5 18a.999.999 0 01-.71-1.71l4.3-4.29-4.3-4.29a1.004 1.004 0 011.42-1.42l5 5a.998.998 0 010 1.42l-5 5a1 1 0 01-.71.29z"></path>
</svg>
```

XPath attempts:

```
//*[name()='svg' and fill='#6C727C']
//*[name()='svg' and @fill="#6C727C"]
//*[name()='svg' and @contain(fill, "#6C727C")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third try was closest.  Change

```
//*[name()='svg' and @contains(fill, "#6C727C")]
```

to

```
//*[name()='svg' and contains(@fill, "#6C727C")]
```

if you want to check that the `fill` attribute value has a substring of `"#6C727C"`, or

```
//*[name()='svg' and @fill="var(--N400, #6C727C)"]
```

if you want to check that the `fill` attribute value exactly equals `"var(--N400, #6C727C)"`

### See also

- [HTML 5, inline SVG, and namespace awareness for SVG DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23319537/290085)
- [CSS `var()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var())